# multiparty encryption and decryption

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption, transmission

Is is possible to send a single encrypted data message to multiple users and the users receiving the message can only decrypt certain parts of the message depending on their rights.

For example, I send a message "Hello World", User A could decrypt can receive the whole message(hello world), but user B only can decrypt certain part and receive the message as "hello" only.

Comment: sure - encrypt the parts with different keys and assume A has both but B only one

Comment: Have a look at Broadcast encryption:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_encryption. It is used by pay-TV systems to only decrypt the channels an user has paid for.

Comment: Cross-posted to [crypto.se]: [Multiparty encryption and decryption](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/32378/13022)